# How to convert Objectify 6.0.9 to Jakarta namespace

Tags: objectify, jakarta-migration

I am upgrading a project from java 8 to java 17, which uses the Jakarta namespace and I make use of Objectify java library to communicate with Google datastore, but the problem is that Objectify 6.0.9 uses javax.servlet.* which does not exist in java 17.

I have searched for a Jakarta version of the Objectify library in the maven repo without success, please how do I convert the Objectify library from javax.servlet.* to jakarta.servlet.* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servlet package is only used by `ObjectifyFilter`, which is two lines of real code:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyFilter.java

Just roll your own filter. All you need is this:

```
try (Closeable closeable = ObjectifyService.begin()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

At some point a future version of Objectify will switch to jakarta.*, but it no doubt cause trouble for other users so I'll probably err on being a little too late rather than too early. Google says they're turning down GAE/Java8 at the end of this year so that's probably a good time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have two jars, the regular and objectify-jakarta jar.

Comment: Kindly consider updating the java doc of ObjectifyFilter.java to include this solution.